# No error output from phing's sshtask

Tags: phing

I'm using phing to run compass as one of the tasks. I'm using `sshTask` for that. Everything works fine when compass executes correctly, but if compass produces error, I get no phing output at all.

My long shot is that phing is capturing only stdout but not capturing stderr and that's why I can't see errors from compass.

How can I make phing to show these errors and how can I fail the build if there are any errors from this command.

Code:

```
<sshtask
  host="${application.${target}.server.host}"
  username="${application.${target}.server.user}"
  pubkeyfile="${pubkey}"
  privkeyfile="${prvkey}"
  command="compass compile ${application.${target}.site.htdocs}"
/>
```